# how can i generate .XAP file in rhomobile

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, rhomobile

how to generate .xap file in rhomobile for windows phone 8.
i have tried :
$ rake device:wm:production

Do we have some way to make/generate this file.

Answer (score 0):

To build for WP8 you should use the command line:

```
rake device:wp8:production
```

More info in the documentation page: [Build for Windows Phone 8](http://docs.rhomobile.com/en/5.0.0/guide/build_wp8)

You can get a complete list of commands running:

```
rake -T
```

the command you used is to build Windows Mobile application: [Build for Windows Mobile](http://docs.rhomobile.com/en/5.0.0/guide/build_wm).

Keep in mind that support for Windows Phone8 will be improved in the upcoming RhoMobile Suite v5.1 planned for later this year. You can follow the development on [rhomobile github account](https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes).